# Variable containing loop

Tags: php, variables, loops

I am not sure if this is even possible or if it makes sense but I want to set a variable to contain this loop:

```
<?php
do{
$x = $x + 1;
} while ($x<=5);
?>
```

Can this be accomplished with a variable variable?

Comment: `Variable to contain this loop` WHAAT?

Comment: Do you mean a function?

Comment: I might. I'm not sure, I just want to set the above loop as a variable so I can use it other places

Comment: if you are trying something like this `$thisisloop = for($i=0; $i <=10; $i++) {    //this is not possible }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're looking to create a function:

```
function fun($x) {
    do {
        $x = $x + 1;
    } while ($x <= 5);
    return $x;
}
```

Then in your code you can simply write:

```
$x = fun($x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
<?php
$varVar = rand(0,10);
for ($i=1; $i<=$varVar; $i++)
{/*the loop*/}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean, unless you're after something similar to the block syntax of Objective-C?

I'm presuming you're new to PHP, and if so, are you sure you're not looking for functions? What you've done above will make the value of $x equal 5, if you wanted to do this with a function it would look like:

```
<?php
function doSomething($count) {
    do {
         // do something here
    } while ($x <= $count);
}

doSomething(5);
?>
```